# The equivalent of #define number 4 in C#

Tags: c#

How can I write the equivalent of C++ code line:

```
#define number 4
```

in C#

Comment: @HimBromBeere in C# you can define that symbols exist, so `#define number` is fine - but you can't give them values (like `4`)

Comment: @MarcGravell Yeap, I missed the value-thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest that exists in C# is a `const`:

```cs
const int number = 4;
```

This must be inside a type, note.

Comment: So if I'm using this number in a struct, it won't be recognized inside that struct

Comment: @temp you would need to qualify it to a scope where it is defined, for example `SomeType.number` - and have appropriate accessibility (perhaps `internal`)